# Dig into translation tables

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate to deal with i18n in my app.
Somehow when user logs out then in again, one of the tables disappear.

Is there a way to check out translation tables, for debug purpose ?

I'm using a `$translateProvider` like this :

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
    $translateProvider.useLoader('i18nLoader', {});
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('EN');
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
}])
```